# Помогите настроить стили CSS

Tags: css

Есть у меня три блока. Второй на всю ширину экрана, первый и третий на 50% от ширины экрана. Прилагаю скрин.

```
<div class="w50">one</div>
<div class="w100">two</div>
<div class="w50">three</div>
```

[image: Как это сейчас отображается]

Как CSS настроить так, чтобы третий блок отобразился возле первого справа? Поменять местами блоки не могу, потому что блоки генерируются автоматически, и их может быть много в произвольном порядке.

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет? https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/wb2a07n6/

Comment: не подойдет, потому, что на месте третьего блока может быть первый. я не знаю как они сгенерируются - код динамичный

Comment: у вас написан только 1 вопрос: "Как CSS настроить так, чтобы третий блок отобразился возле первого справа?", и на него ответили чётко и ясно, если есть другие вопросы задайте, если блоков может быть много, то задайте вопрос более глобально, например: "Как настроить css так, чтобы каждые 2 блока в множестве становились рядом друг с другом, игнорируя блоки шириной 100%?", и приводите соответствующую картинку, хотя я по-прежнему не уверен, что как и другие правильно понимаю вопрос из-за расплывчатости формулировок

Comment: организуйте свой код так, чтобы каждые 2 блока 50% имели свою обёртку в html, независимо от попадания блоков 100%, и используйте вариант, который предложил @soledar10

Comment: скорее всего так и сделаю, но не хотелось бы менять алгоритм генерации блоков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По моему никак, только поменять местами блоки или же стилями как написали выше. Совет: поменяйте алгоритм генерации Ваших блоков.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.w50{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  float: left;
}

.w100{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  clear: both;
}

div{
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.three{
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="w50 one">one</div>
<div class="w100 two">two</div>
<div class="w50 three">three</div>
```

Comment: Повторю еще раз "блоки генерируются автоматически, и их может быть много в произвольном порядке." так каким образом я узнаю к каким блокам добавить top: -100px?

Comment: так перепишы алгоритм генерирования )

Comment: не надо этого делать, эти блоки еще должны мышкой перетягиваться, меняться местами

Comment: тогда свойствами CSS никак, JS вам в помощь...

Comment: уже думаю над этим. но хотелось бы без js

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Насколько я помню из презентации гридов- там можно блоки ставить как душе угодно.